# AWS CodeCommit Policy to disable push in master

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I created a new user in AWS IAM. In  the user is not defined any policy of security.

After create user , i created a new policy with values:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:GitPush",
            "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
            "codecommit:PutFile",
            "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:222222:repositoty",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                "codecommit:References": [
                    "refs/heads/master"
                ]
            },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Then I associated this policy to the new user, but in all branches of the repository he has error 403. Even in the branch he created himself.
It can't pull and push its own branches

Comment: For me, the user could push to all branches including the master.... After removing the condition "Null", the user could not push to all branches

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved the issue in the past one year when this question was posted. Maybe this answer could help someone else.

I switched from GitHub to CodeCommit recently and I was looking for some similar and could do it successfully. The main issue I see in your policy is you are explicitly denying permissions. There is no actions allowed. Not denying something is not considered as allowing. I attached the following policy to the users group.

The result is all users with this policy cannot push anything to the main branch but can do it by a PR (not FF). An additional improvement on this would be a Approval Template but that is out of scope for this question.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:*" # Can be further refined
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:123456:first-app"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:PutFile",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:123456:first-app",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/main",
                        "refs/heads/master"
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "codecommit:References": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```